# Testing query speed using non-cached data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2014.  A query I have takes 44 seconds to run the first time I run it.  After that it takes 6 seconds.  I'm sure this is because the data is cached in memory (and possibly because the query plan is cached as well).  I want to find ways to speed up my query so the first time it's taking 6 seconds, but it's hard to test that when everything is cached.

How can I force my query to NOT used cached data?  Or to put it another way, how can I force my query to run like it's the first time every time?

I tried adding option `recompile` but that didn't make any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` forces SQL Server to evict all (unmodified) data it's put in the buffer cache; `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` throws away query plans. These are server wide and have a huge impact on a production machine, so only use them on a machine you're pretty much using exclusively on your own.

Comment: Is you intent is to measure query performance or IO system performance? A warm cache is fine for the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [SQL Server `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-dropcleanbuffers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). From the documentation:

> Use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache without shutting down and restarting the server.

This command can be used in conjonction with [`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Clearing the procedure (plan) cache causes all plans to be evicted, and incoming query executions will compile a new plan, instead of reusing any previously cached plan.

Disclaimer: please consider the impacts of such command before running it; this should be used for testing purposes only, in non-Production environments!

Comment: Thanks.  I knew about DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and the consequences of doing it on a production system.  Didn't know about DROPCLEANBUFFERS.  Unfortunately I'm on a production system and was hoping there was just something like the recompile option to tell it to ignore the cache.  But this does help a lot for when I'm on our dev system.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Note that that `CHECKPOINT` is needed before `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`. Also, SQL Server performs full extent reads rather than single page reads when the cache isn't warmed up (http://www.dbdelta.com/performance-testing-with-dbcc-dropcleanbuffers/).

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic issue and sometimes you are in PD environment where it may not be desirable to clear cache like this.

It is always best to look at query plan and not worry about how long query took.  Analyze the plan and then see where it may have gone wrong.  A query is good because plan is good and execution time should be secondary.  Simply trust the user's statement that it was slow and dont go off on a tangent that [it is running fine now].  It is running fine if plan looks good.